# Spark rdd unique values across a paired rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

> I have a Spark RDD of this datatype: RDD[(Int, Array[Int])])
>
> Sample values of that RDD are:
>
> 100, Array(1,2,3,4,5)
>
> 200,Array(1,2,50,20)
>
> 300, Array(30,2,400,1)
>
> I would like to get all the unique values among all the Array elements
>   of this RDD I don't care about the key, just want to get all the
>   unique values. So the result from the above sample is
>   (1,2,3,4,5,20,30,50,400).
>
> What will be an efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should probably work:

```
val result = rdd.flatMap(_._2).distinct
```

if you want the result in an `RDD`, or

```
val result = rdd.flatMap(_._2).distinct.collect
```

if you want the result in a local collection.