# Get unique RDD strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created the following sample RDD,

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("something1@domainA.com"), 
                              ("something2@domainA.com"), 
                              ("something3@domainB.com")))

//I used the following to split,

val rdd1 = rdd.map(_.split("@")) //RDD[Array[String]]
```

What I am trying to do now is to get a new RDD with distinct domains, i.e.

```
val finalrdd = sc.parallelize(List(("domainA"), 
                                   ("domainB")))
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469244/spark-rdd-unique-values-across-a-paired-rdd) but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
rdd.map(_.split("@")).flatMap { case Array(_, d) => d.split("\\.").headOption }.distinct
```